# URL redirect using Windows DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, url, internal-dns

I have a website say xyzuniversity.com/north.
I want to redirect college.com to be redirected to xyzuniversity.com/north using Windows DNS entries.

Is there a process to do this?

Also what are the possible ways to do this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please check the below scenario and let me know how we can fix it. I used IIS HTTPredirect to redirect college.com to xyzuniversity.com/north & created a DNS entry for college.com. 1) When I am using college.com in IE, it is redirected successfully 2) When I use www.college.com or http ://www.college.com, it is not redirected to xyzuniversity.com/north. Sometimes I am redirected to bing search results or page cannot be displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS doesn't work like that, it maps names to IP addresses or other names, and that's all.

Redirection of the kind you mention is done by a web server such as IIS, which would need to be configured to handle requests for http://college.com, and return an HTTP redirect code/location to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am into a different issue now. Please check the below scenario and let me know how we can fix it. I used IIS HTTPredirect to redirect college.com to xyzuniversity.com/north & created a DNS entry for college.com. 1) When I am using college.com in IE, it is redirected successfully 2) When I use www.college.com or http ://www.college.com, it is not redirected to xyzuniversity.com/north. Sometimes I am redirected to bing search results or page cannot be displayed.

Comment: You will have to create a DNS record and redirect in the same way. There's nothing magical about the "www" name used by sites, its simply a convention. If you want it to exist, you must make it exist by creating the DNS entry, etc.

Comment: This is the tested results which I have commented above.  1) When I am using college.com in IE, it is redirected successfully 2) When I use www.college.com or http ://www.college.com, it is not redirected to xyzuniversity.com/north.

However I have done a workaround for this - created a college.com DNS zone. Created a parent entry (i.e Blank Host entry pointing to an IP) and also one "www" host entry pointing to the same IP. so that college.com or www.college.com are pointing to the same IP. This worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Point college.com at a server (maybe the xyzuniversity.com server) then on that server set up a site in Apache/IIS/whatever for college.com. 
The index page of that college.com site on the xyzuniversity.com server should be a redirect to xyzuniversity.com/north Use whatever redirect mechanism you want (PHP, ASP, Apache, IIS, .htaccess...) but ideally you want to have it issue an "HTTP 301 permanently moved" response code.